# Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

Tags: support

I noticed a couple of questions related to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo had been tagged as `delphi-tokyo` instead of as `delphi-10.2-tokyo` (which has 203 questions). When I try to suggest `delphi-tokyo` as a synonym for `delphi-10.2-tokyo`, I get this error.

> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

I edited the questions to use `delphi-10.2-tokyo` instead, but I'm just curious to know why the synonym was blocked?

Comment: Because someone through that only mods should create x-v to x synonyms.

Comment: @Braiam but I was trying to make an x to x-v synonym instead.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? As soon as a new version is linked the synonym would be bad as the tag would be incorrect for the version they are talking about. What is so wrong about having a generic version of the tag instead of the version specific tag?

Comment: @JoeW I think you misunderstand what I'm saying. Tokyo is a specific version of Delphi. A version-specific tag already existed for it (`delphi-10.2-tokyo`) but a couple of questions were marked with a different tag instead (`delphi-tokyo`). Still version specific, just without the version number. So I tried to make `delphi-tokyo` be a synonym for `delphi-10.2-tokyo`, but failed. So I edited the questions instead to fix the tagging. But since it already happened twice, it will probably happen again